# Python PIL read/open TIFF is black only

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, tiff

I try to read a TIFF file with pillow/PIL (7.2.0) in Python (3.8.3), e.g. [this image](http://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/tif/moon.tif).

The resulting file seems to be corrupted:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

myimage = Image.open('moon.tif')
myimage.mode
# 'L'
myimage.format
# 'TIFF'
myimage.size
# (358, 537)

# so far all good, but:
np.array(myimage)
# shows only zeros in the array, likewise
np.array(myimage).sum()
# 0
```

It doesn't seem to be a problem of the conversion to numpy array only, since if I save it to a jpg (`myimage.save('moon.jpg')`) the resulting jpg image has the appropriate dimensions but is all black, too.

Where did I do wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: I'm using Windows, if it matters

Comment: I think there must be some issue with your installation - your code works as expected on my machine.

Comment: yeah, i suppose that it's the installation. but i have no clue what to change...

Comment: I don't use Windows, but on a Mac I would uninstall PIL/Pillow and `libtiff` then re-install `lifbtff` first followed by PIL/Pillow.

Comment: what tiffinfo or identify say about your images ? not sure you have both of them on windows

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in coding but i had same problem and found the TIFF file has 4 layers. R, G ,B and Alpha. When you convert it using PIL it is black.

try to view the image as plt.imshow(myimage[:, :, 0])
you could also remove the Alpha layer by saving the read image ( i used plt.imread('image')) and then saving it as  image=image[:,:,3]. Now its a RGB image.

I don't know if i answered your question, but i felt this info might be of help.